# onload function and onclick not working in jsp

Tags: html, hide

i m trying to hide a field depending on onlcik of a radio button but its not working. Also please suggest if i want to hide group of fields at single onclick..i can't use div inside table and i have tried for tbody tag also but still not working

```
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script language=javascript>
function hide() {
    var div_ref = document.getElementsByTagId("trr");
      div_ref.style.visibility = "hidden";

}
function show() {
    var div_ref = document.getElementById("trr");
      div_ref.style.visibility = "visible";
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="hide()">
<h1> Translate HSM</h1>
<form action="" method="post">
    <table style="with: 50%">

        <tr id="trr" >
            <td >Enter HSM IP Address</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="ip_address" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Please Select Option for Read the HSM keys</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="readOption" value="manual" onclick="hide()">Enter keys Manually</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="readOption" value="DB" onclick="show()">Read HSM Keys from DB</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it a typo on the statement `getElementsByTagId`? shoule be `getElementById`?

```js
function hide() {
  var div_ref = document.getElementById("trr");
  div_ref.style.visibility = "hidden";

}

function show() {
  var div_ref = document.getElementById("trr");
  div_ref.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

```html
<body onload="hide()">
  <h1> Translate HSM</h1>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <table style="with: 50%">

      <tr id="trr">
        <td>Enter HSM IP Address</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="ip_address" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Please Select Option for Read the HSM keys</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="readOption" value="manual" onclick="hide()">Enter keys Manually</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="readOption" value="DB" onclick="show()">Read HSM Keys from DB</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I think you should pre-select "Read HSM Keys from DB" by default as well, otherwise no matter choose either option, the HSM text field will show. Which seems to be a logical error on the UI design to me.

Comment: Yes its working now. It was typo :-P Thanks Mr. Brickowski :-)

Comment: ok, that i have removed it purposefully for testing. I have a small question here. can i call two functions on a single onlick ? As i have two groups(group of fields) that should be made visible and invisible on a single field. If I click manual.. 1st group should get visible and other invisble ....if  selected DB then 1st should get invisible and second to get visible ?

Comment: Technically, yes. i.e. you can write your html as onclick=”functionA();functionB();”.

Comment: But it would be another topic it is a good practice or not and it is subject to the application design. There are many ways to achieve the purpose of toggle visibility of two groups. For example. generalize the visibility toggle mechanism so it would take the id of the group as a parameter (lets name it function toggleGroup(groupId) ). Then toggleGroup() would fit different groups. Under your radio onclick event, issue one function (say radioOnclick()). Under radioOnclick(), issue two toggleGroup() calls. That is one possible way.

Comment: Okay... got it.. thanks for the valuable information Locus :-)

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider accepting the answer if it solves the problem. Thank you.